# How do you read data from a Boost Property Tree that uses JSon?

Tags: json, boost

I have a JSon formatted txt document full of some options for a program. I'm loading this into a property tree using Boost's json_reader.  My issue is that I can't figure out how to access the data within said property tree.  I've looked over the documentation and it's just not working for me. I don't know if it's because the documentation only addresses XML format or what.

The format for my options file is as follows

```
{
    "Program_Version": "",
    "value": 700,
    "age": 2,
    "size": 2,

    "File":
    {
      "FileName": "cat",
      "Username": "felix", 
    },
}
```

How would I go about accessing the value for FileName for example?

Comment: Did you try `pt.get<std::string>("File.FileName");`?

Comment: That works for that case, but if I do 
    pt.get<std::string>("File.Username");
I don't get anything.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma following "felix" and also the comma on the second to last brace.  JSON does not expect a comma following the last value at any level.  Those commas are likely interfering with the read-in of the data.